# Asp.net core Identity Signs in user without password from any device

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Let me explain the situation I'm running into as it seems I'm the first one in the whole internet to deal with it and I ran out of ideas. I have a pretty simple Razor Pages website that is running on asp.net core 3.0 It is hosted on the Azure App Service. I am using the most standard Idenity Framework Provided By Microsoft. Here is my Startup.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IIHF_Toolbox.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace IIHF_Toolbox
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSession();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sOptions =>
                    {
                        sOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(20);
                    }), ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
            });
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    //        services.AddControllers()
    //.AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.                                                                                                                        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("MYAPIKEY");
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            //app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it looks pretty standart.As you can see, I use the simplest login-password Sign-In mechanism with default IdentityUser. Now about the problem:

I login into my website with User-A, using it's credentials. Then, I open my website on a brand clean device that never previously visited the websites, nor logged into it, and I find out that somehow, that I'm signed in to the User-A without entering a password on a device that never visited this website before. This is more that a security bteach. This is basically the absence of security. And you've gussed it right - If I provide you with a link, and you follow it, you will basically enter website already logged into a User-A account.

N.B. The link to the website could be any - it is not something like if you follow "website.com/user-a" you'll get to his page with edit rights. The thing is that SignInManager.IsUserSignedIn(User) and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated both returns true. Maybe I'm misunderstanding that? But how in the world would brand new Session be injected with the same user as the last logged in one? I'm really running out of ideas. Any idea on what to check would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And could you please show how your controller looks ? Does it have an `Authorize` somewhere (methods, controller class)?

Comment: Show us everything that has anything even remotely related to identity. Or just show us everything you see here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: **The order of Middleware is important!** Fix your middleware order, read [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-3.1#order) and see if the Session middleware was somehow preventing the Authentication Middleware from doing its job.